# Safe way to resolve Java Path

Tags: java, path

I try to safely resolve a external received String against a "root path".
Safely means in this case it should be impossible to provide a String which causes the resulting Path to point to a path outside of the root directory. A possible symlink could be ignored.
My current idea is:

```
public static Path safeResolve(Path root, String subname) {
    Path subpath = root.resolve(subname).normalize();
    if(subpath.startsWith(root))
        return subpath;
    return null;
}
```

this seems to be safe as long the root is already normalized.
Is this ok or is there a better / safer way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `root` is already normalized, this solution will work fine.

Although you said that symlinks could be ignored, note that such cases can be easily covered using [`Files.isSymbolicLink()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isSymbolicLink(java.nio.file.Path)):

```
public static Path safeResolve(Path root, String subname) {
    Path subpath = root.normalize().resolve(subname).normalize();
    if(subpath.startsWith(root) && !Files.isSymbolicLink(subpath))
        return subpath;
    return null;
}
```